# Deleting lines begin with # but not the line #!/bin/ksh

Tags: sed

How can I delete lines that begin with `#` but not `#!/bin/ksh`?

Using `sed -e '/^#/ d' sed.sh` will delete every line including `#!/bin/ksh`.

Comment: assuming you don't want to delete `#!/bin/ksh` only from first line of file, you can add addressing... `sed -e '2,${/^#/d}'`

Comment: I *think* that adding the expression `1p`, to print the first line, would work. This would make the entire thing `sed -e '1p' -e '/^#/d'`. If you actually want to keep all lines which are `#!/bin/ksh`, and not just the first, then you would need to replace the `1` in `1p` with `/#!\/bin\/ksh/`.

Comment: @Sundeep thanks you. What if #!/bin/ksh is not in the first line?

Comment: Then I think you could do `/^#!\/bin\/ksh/!{/^#/d}`. That does the `/^#/d` part on all lines which don’t match `/^#!\/bin\/ksh/`.

Comment: @Daniel H Thanks alot. That's what I was looking for.

Comment: @Sundeep, it was really your solution; you should write it up as an answer.

Comment: If `#!/bin/ksh` is not the first line, then it's not acting as a shebang and might as well be deleted.

Comment: @William, I think the point was that `#foo` could be the first line, and that wouldn't get deleted.

Comment: Note that `#! /bin/ksh` is also a valid shebang (with a space after the exclamation).

Answer (score 0):

```
 Thanks @Daniel H
 sed -e '/#!\/bin\/ksh/p' -e '/^#/d' sed.sh
```

this is the command that gave the result I was looking for:

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
sed '/^#/{/^#!\/bin\/ksh/d}' sed.sh
```

For all lines that start with a `#`, if they don't start with `#!/bin/ksh`, delete them.

Since comments (and the shebang line) might have spaces in front, more precise would be

```
sed '/^[[:space:]]*#/{/^[[:space:]]*#![[:space:]]*\/bin\/ksh/d}' sed.sh
```